# Is it possible to somehow automatically create jobs in TestLink from Jenkins?

Tags: testing, jenkins, testlink

I'm doing a bit of reasearch on Jenkins and TestLink and I was wondering - is it possible to automatically generate new project/job in TestLink or does it always have to be done manually? The issue is that I would like to run tests on Jenkins and then all the test that failed should create a new job in TestLink.

Is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default TestLink Jenkins plugin you can't create new projects automatically on TestLink. You will end up in below type of error

```
FATAL: Test Project (name:TestSample1234) does not exist.
    br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Test Project (name:TestSample1234) does not exist.
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.checkResponseError(BaseService.java:113)
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.executeXmlRpcCall(BaseService.java:91)
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestProjectService.getTestProjectByName(TestProjectService.java:112)
        at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.getTestProjectByName(TestLinkAPI.java:438)
        at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:309)
        at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:186)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:906)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:857)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
    ERROR: Error communicating with TestLink. Check your TestLink configuration.
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Maybe you can achieve this by customizing the Jenkin plugin, please have look in plugin code [1] and [2]
or asked from testlink forum
[1] https://github.com/jenkinsci/testlink-plugin
[2] https://github.com/kinow/testlink-java-api

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange and thank you for the answer. To understand the process better, please go though this link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Under **Test Execution** -> *Test Reports and Metrics* you will be able to filter out only the failed tests.

This can be exported, the icon is quite hidden on the top left, as an excel.
Possibly doing some work on that file you can be able to generate a test suite with only the failed tests